# How to check if an object has a specific key without try/catch

Tags: javascript

I am receiving this JSON from server, and I need to check if it contains the key `read.nores`

[image]

if I do it like this

```
if (data[0]["read.nores"]) {
    return;
}
```

it will crash because it does not contain that key.

How can I check if the key is there without a try/catch method, something like .has("read.nores")?

Comment: It does contain that key … and even if it didn't, it wouldn't crash, it would just get the `undefined` value (which is falsy, so it wouldn't return)

Comment: have you tried `indexOf()` ?

Comment: It will only crash if `data[0]` isn't available, so you would need to check that before like `if(data[0] && data[0]["read.nores"])`

Comment: actually this will not crash for the key, could crash for the index of array if is misisng you could try if(data[0] && data[0][key])

Comment: Object.keys(obj).indexOf('read.nores')

Comment: you can also use obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) function to check if key exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading an undefined key safely produces `undefined`, but reading a key from `undefined` will throw, so the problem will be specifically that `data[0]` doesn't exist, not that `data[0]["read.nores"]` doesn't exist.

To check for that, change it to:

```
if (data[0] && data[0]["read.nores"]) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: This does not check if the object contains a key 'read.nores', since its value could also be a falsey value.

Comment: Sure, but the OP's problem was that his code was throwing, not that falsy values were being ignored.

Comment: The question was "How can I check if the key is there without a try/catch method". I did not downvote it since it probably is enough, yet it does not answer the question. That is all.

Comment: this answer seems to work fine for me, since the response I am receiving is either a JSONObject with the read.nores key, or few json objects with arrays in them

Answer (score 1):

It won't crash.
If you check any property of an object and it is not defined in the object it is by default `undefined`. So your if condition will work perfectly.

Comment: The condition to check 'if the json contains the key' will not work, since it validates false on falsey values even if the key actually exists.